# PHP Curl with Variables

Tags: php, curl, shell-exec

I am trying to pass a few variables to the shell_exec command, but for some reason it's not picking up the data in the php variables. Please help me, and the below is what I got:

```
$out = exec('curl -silent https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges -u sk_live_sdfsdfdsfsdfdf: -d "amount=$aaamount" -d currency=usd -d "description=BBB $aaamount" -d "card[number]=$ccnumber" -d "card[exp_month]=$expm" -d "card[exp_year]=$expy" -d "card[cvc]=611"');
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Single quoted strings won't parse variables; use double quotes http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: You're aware that [PHP has bindings to cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), right?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart what does that mean :) ?

Comment: @thevoipman Click the link :-)

Answer (score 2):

You're aware that [PHP has bindings to cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), right?

Besides, on the very front page of [Stripe](https://stripe.com/), right where you probably copied that `curl` command line, is a drop-down to change to other languages, namely PHP.  They have an API for you to use:

```
require_once('./lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_mkGsLqEW6SLnZa487HYfJVLf");

Stripe_Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 400,
  "currency" => "usd",
  "card" => array(
    "number" => "4242424242424242",
    "exp_month" => 6,
    "exp_year" => 2014,
    "cvc" => 314
  ),
  "description" => "Charge for test@example.com")
);
```

Comment: Well your current code structure obviously isn't working, right? Why not do it the *right* way then and use their API?

Comment: i substitute single quotes with double quotes, now it's working, thanks anyways.

Comment: Sigh, some people never get it.

Comment: Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
  
try{
  $customer = Stripe_Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $stripCode
  ));}
  catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
try{
 $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $order_amount, // amount in cents
    "customer"=>$customer->id,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com",
    "application_fee" => 123 // amount in cents
  ));  }
 catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->getMessage();
  }

It gives an error and charge is not created!!

Comment: @Prince If you have a problem, ask a new question. Don't post a blob of unreadable code in the comments. If you feel so inclined, you could post a comment here linking to your new question.

Comment: I am not able to determine where I am getting wrong in implementing curl and stripe in php??

Comment: @Prince **Again**, [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question; don't hijack the comments on this one for a new problem.